# Why webpack try to resolve unimport file?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

Why webpack try to parse error.ts file? I don't import this file in any place

Here my application structure:

**myapp/src/app.ts**

```
import {some} from './some';

console.log('from some', some);
```

**myapp/src/some.ts**

```
export const some = 1;
```

**myapp/src/error.ts**

```
import { exist } from 'libnotexist';

console.log('not exist', exist);
```

**myapp/src/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
  }
}
```

**myapp/webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const {
  CheckerPlugin,
  TsConfigPathsPlugin
} = require('awesome-typescript-loader');

const configFileName = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/tsconfig.json');

module.exports = () => [
  {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/app.ts'),
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
      plugins: [new TsConfigPathsPlugin({ configFileName })]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
          query: { configFileName }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
  }
];
```

**myapp/package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.21.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
```

**I got Webpack Error:**

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/error.ts:1:23
TS2307: Cannot find module 'libnotexist'.
```

Any ideas why webpack give this error? I not include this file in any place

Comment: what happens if you remove `new CheckerPlugin()` from plugins?

Comment: @axm__ no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`tsconfig` docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> If the "files" and "include" are both left unspecified, the compiler
>   defaults to including all TypeScript (.ts, .d.ts and .tsx) files in
>   the containing directory and subdirectories except those excluded
>   using the "exclude" property.

So you should add `files: []` to your `tsconfig.json`, and all other files will ignored.